# Excel: Object Text Box can't do Carriage Returns in Protected vs. Unprotected Sheet states (w/ Text Unlocked)...why?

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, activex

First and foremost, my due diligence rounded up a ton of answers regarding ActiveX Text Boxes, but nothing really about Object Text Boxes.  For my project, I cannot use any ActiveX.

OK, so when a Sheet is Unprotected, an Object Text Box (from Insert > Shapes) works pretty much the way I want it to: the most important thing being that I can hit the Enter key and get a carriage return.  Then, I go into the Shape Properties, and uncheck Lock Text, and protect the sheet.

Once the sheet is protected, though, the ability to do carriage returns (type Enter, and go down one line) goes away.  Shift+Enter and Alt+Enter are no-goes as well.

Is it just not possible to have this functionality available?  Are there any workarounds?  Why does Excel hate me?  Here are some of my ideas:

- Unprotect Sheet when Text Box is clicked/activated, Protect when not
  (couldn't figure out the syntax in VBA for this.  "If Intersect..." is what I'm thinking)
- Insert Word Doc Object (don't like this because one-click enters the
  formula bar editing, and I can't get the font to stay)
- Just use a merged cell and instruct users to double-click to enter
  and use Alt+Enter for a new line.

The winning option for now is using a merged cell, but I may just have to see if ActiveX will work on our network.  I really want to stick to the KISS principle here if at all possible for the end user...I don't mind coding in the backend to make it work, though.

Thank you for your thoughts!

**EDIT:** Here's some images to help...

Here's the functionality that I would like to have when my Sheet is protected:
[image: Unprotected Text Box Shape]

Next, this is an ActiveX text box with it's properties window displayed (Developer > Design Mode > Properties).  The properties that make it somewhat usable when the Sheet is protected are circled in red, the Multiline and Enter Key Behavior.  But again, I'd prefer to not have to use ActiveX...plus, the user cannot change font color by line.

[image: ActiveX Text Box]

Finally, I found this interesting: There is another Text box under Form Control that is grayed out.  From a search, it looks like this was taken away in favor of the drawing objects version of the text box...or maybe it's the same?  The left is the drawing objects one, the middle is the grayed out Form Control, and the right is the ActiveX.

[image]

In sum, I would just like to see if there is a way to have the functionality of an unprotected Sheet's Shapes Text Box when the sheet is protected.

Comment: Do you mean a Text Box (form control) or a Text Box (shape)?

Comment: I guess it would be a Text Box (Shape).  The one that derives from Insert > Shapes.

Comment: When sheet is protected under ordinary circumstances, I can't even *edit* a Textbox shape at all.

Comment: The ability to type *anything* in a shape is not allowed, when the sheet is protected.

Comment: @DavidZemens I just tested typing in a shape, and was able to add text with that shape's "Lock Text" unchecked in Shape Options, and checking "Edit Objects" when I protected the sheet.  Of course, using the Enter key took me off of the object.

Comment: I noticed the same thing with the greyed out  Text Field control.  Maybe I mistakenly used the ActiveX variety... or maybe there was some trick to use that form control. I will try to double check when I'm back in front of a my laptop (I'm on mobile right now).

Comment: [This](http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/form-controls-disabled-text-box-combolist-and-combodropdown.11594/) is interesting. Suggests that you can use this control on an Excel 5.0 Dialog (I have no idea what this is, it's the first I've ever heard of it...) and then simply paste the controls over in to your normal spreadsheet.  That might work...

Comment: What in the what is THAT?  HA ha...never knew that existed.  So, I open a 5.0 Dialog and insert the Text Box that's been grayed out.  No font formatting, and you can't even see where your cursor is!  Well, at least I learned something new...thanks again for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with a TextBox *shape*, inserted from the ribbon, here:

[image]

Then you can use the optional parameter in the `Protect` method:

```
Sheet1.Protect DrawingObjects:=False
```

This will allow the user to edit text boxes on the worksheet, but the sheet itself will remain protected.

If you are using a Form Control (inserted from the Develper/Design ribbon) then you can set the `.MultiLine` property by accessing the shape's `OLEFormat.Object`:

```
Sub test()

Dim tb As Shape
Dim x As Object

'Get a handle on the SHAPE
Set tb = ActiveSheet.Shapes(2)
'You have to access its properties from the OLEFormat.Object:
tb.OLEFormat.Object.Object.MultiLine = True

End Sub
```

In my test, even on a Protected worksheet this allows the user to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert carriage returns:

[image]

Comment: David, thank you for the detailed response and taking the time snipping images.  It tells me that we're both looking at the same thing.

The first part of your answer, using a Text Box shape from the Insert ribbon, I've tried doing it both ways: Protecting the sheet with "Edit Objects" + "Select Unlocked Cells" checked AND via the code you provided (that's what I found in my search results).  I'm pretty sure that `Sheet1.Protect DrawingObjects:=False` is doing the same action as "Select Unlocked Cells"...correct?

For the second part, I only have ActiveX Text Box as an option. See my OP edit.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Shift + Enter seems to work on a protected sheet.